# android zoom mapView like maps App

Tags: android, zooming, android-mapview

when I stop to zoom (pinch to zoom) on a mapView, the zoom continues until it reaches a zoom level whereas Google maps app stop.
I would like to have maps-like behavior.
Can I have that ? 
thanks

edit : can i have an onZoomListener for pinch to zoom (like for zoomsButtonscontroller) ?

Comment: please show us how you implemented the pinch to zoom.

Comment: I just use the standard mapView pinch to zoom

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want exactly but this might help you: `mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);`

From the documentation:

> Sets whether to enable the built-in zoom controls. If enabled, the MapView will show these zoom controls automatically.
>
> Parameters:
>           on - Whether the built-in zoom controls are enabled. If false, the client handles showing the UI for zoom controls.

Comment: it's not that I want. I speak about pinch to zoom. after I do a zoom the mapView continues to be zoomed until the next zoom level. in the maps app, when I stop to zoom, the map remains as it is

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please work a bit on your language and your grammar. Slang or abbreviation should be avoided.

Comment: @robert: please add this information to your question, because it is very important to know for us

Answer (score 0):

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

MapController mc;
mc = mapView.getController();
```

Use it you may be got your solution.